# Converting dp to px without Context

Tags: android, screen-size, pixel-density

There is a very neat way of converting dp to px without Context, and it goes like this:

```
public static int dpToPx(int dp) {
    float density = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    return Math.round((float) dp * density);
}
```

In every Google's example on [Google GitHub page](https://github.com/googlesamples) they are using the following approach:

```
public static int convertDpToPixel(Context ctx, int dp) {
    float density = ctx.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    return Math.round((float) dp * density);
}
```

So is there something wrong with the first approach? For me it works fine in all my apps, but I want to know is there some case where it might fail?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> is there some case where it might fail?

**Yes, there is!**

Android supports different screens, for example you might cast the app with Chromecast or connect to a different screen by other means. In that case the values will not be converted properly to that other screen.

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getSystem()) for `Resources.getSystem()`:

> Return a global shared Resources object that provides access to only
>   system resources (no application resources), and is not configured for
>   the current screen (can not use dimension units, does not change based
>   on orientation, etc).

Comment: Thanks. In my case app doesn't have "cast" option, but it probably can fail on strange devices [like this one](https://www.asus.com/us/Phone/ASUS_PadFone_X_US/).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little Kotlin extension function for that:

```
private fun Context.dpToPx(dp: Float): Float {
    val density = this.resources.displayMetrics.density
    return (dp * density).roundToInt().toFloat()
}
```